# Splash with Music onPause issue

Tags: android, splash-screen

Im new to android and trying to fix error happend with me while try to add splash with music to my app , bellow the code to start three option begining of app depend on user  Preference but still get force closed ,

please any help will be appreciated .

```
public class Splash extends Activity{
MediaPlayer ourSong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.splash); 

        SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());                 

         boolean without_splash_screen = getPrefs.getBoolean("without_splash_screen", true);
            if (without_splash_screen == true)
            {   
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                       startActivity(intent);}

    boolean splash = getPrefs.getBoolean("splash", true);       
    if(splash == true) {
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);  
        Thread timer = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    sleep(1000); 
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
                finally
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                      startActivity(intent);
                }
            }                          
        };
        timer.start();   
    }                 
    boolean splash_music = getPrefs.getBoolean("splash_music", true);
    if (splash_music)    {         
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);  
        ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound);        
        ourSong.start();
        Thread timer = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    sleep(1000); 
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
                finally
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                      startActivity(intent);
                }
            }                          
        };
        timer.start();              
    }
    }       
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        ourSong.start();
        finish();
              } 
            }
```

LOGCAT:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.test.demo/com.test.demo.Splash}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.test.demo.Splash.onPause(Splash.java:89)
at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3862)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1191)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
```

Comment: I guess, it's throwing exception because of `finish()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `our_song` is `null` if `splash_music` is `false` so you will want to change your `onPause()` to check for that

```
  @Override
  protected void onPause() 
  {               
      super.onPause();
      if (ourSong != null)
      {
          ourSong.start();
      }
      finish();
   }
```

Although, I'm not sure why you are calling `start()` there. Did you mean `stop()`?

Comment: thanks my friend , app start ok and you can check any checkbox but when you chose (splash_music) checkbox , app star with splash and music but music doesnt finish with splash before go to next activity, thanks

Comment: music must stop with splash before go to next activity as i set  sleep(1000);, but splash finished and go to next activity and music still running in background

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm having trouble understanding what you're saying. Music doesn't stop just because you have `sleep()` that just suspends that thread for that amount of time. The error is that something is `null` at line 89 which I'm guessing is `ourSong.start();`, am I wrong?

Comment: music must stay together with splash screen for 1 second as i set sleep(1000);, this is the normal behaviour but actually what happen is splash start with music for one second and then splash disappear then next activity start but music desnt stop after 1 second still running even we are now in next activity

Comment: both splash and music must finish after 1 second but i have only splash finished not splash with music

Comment: You don't call `ourSong.stop()`. Also, you are getting `NPE` at line 89...what is at that line?

Comment: that is the line : super.onPause();

Comment: Try taking this line `Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                      startActivity(intent);` out of the `finally` block and put it in the `try` after your `sleep()` call

Comment: i did it , the same splash finished but music still running

Comment: You aren't calling `stop()`

Comment: I think you need to change mine to `stop()` as I said in my answe, I'm not sure why you are calling `start()` there instead of `stop()`

Comment: i changed start to stop and uninstall app then install it again it start with splash screen but stack to splash screen not go to nextactivity

Comment: i think i have to implement OnCheckedChangeListener to my code so finally i can check only one check box for preference , unfortunately i dont know how to do it , any help please

Comment: i already start another post would you please check it , thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625830/how-to-add-oncheckedchangelistener-to-splash-checkedboxs-preference

Comment: I will gladly take a look in just a minute. Glad I could help