# Only select one checkbox of splash preference checkedboxs

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have app starting depend on user preferance with three different checkedbox :

1- start app without splash and music .

2- start app with splash only .

3- start app with spalsh and music .

with the below code its work perfectly .

**But still two point to be achieved :**

**FIRST**  only one checkbox should be checked .

**SECOND** after you checked any one  of checkboxs as you prefer then go back to mainactivity , here you can exit the app either by use **back button** or **exit button** which i already have it in my option menu , the problem is that either using **back button** or **exit button** it doesn't respond to first click , i have to click twice to exit the app.

but i cant achieve it ,

any help please will be appreciated .

```
public class Splash extends Activity{   
MediaPlayer ourSong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.splash);  

         SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());                 

         boolean without_splash_screen = getPrefs.getBoolean("without_splash_screen", true);
            if (without_splash_screen == true)
            {   
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                startActivity(intent);
            }

    boolean splash = getPrefs.getBoolean("splash", true);       
    if(splash == true) {
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);  
        Thread timer = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    sleep(2000); 
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
                finally
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                    startActivity(intent);  
                }
            }                          
        };
        timer.start();   
    }                 

    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound); 

    SharedPreferences getPrefs1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean music = getPrefs1.getBoolean("splash_music", true);
    if (music == true)      
    ourSong.start();

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000); }
              catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace(); }
              finally{
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                  startActivity(intent); }}                                 
                                };
         timer.start();   }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();
          } 
       }
```

In xml folder :**prefs.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <CheckBoxPreference android:title="without splash screen" 
              android:defaultValue="true" 
              android:key="without_splash_screen" 
              android:summary="Start app without splash"/> 

    <CheckBoxPreference android:title="splash screen" 
              android:defaultValue="true" 
              android:key="splash" 
              android:summary="Start app with splash only" />

    <CheckBoxPreference android:title="splash screen music" 
              android:defaultValue="true" 
              android:key="splash_music" 
              android:summary="Start app with splash and music" /> 

 </PreferenceScreen>
```

**UPDATE:**

i tried also the below code but it doesn't change any thing , still all chechboxs can be checked :

```
public class Splash extends Activity{   
MediaPlayer ourSong;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.splash);  

     SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());                 

         boolean without_splash_screen = getPrefs.getBoolean("without_splash_screen", true);
            if (without_splash_screen == true)               
            {   
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                startActivity(intent);                      
            }
    boolean splash = getPrefs.getBoolean("splash", true);       
    if(splash == true) {
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);  
        Thread timer = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    sleep(2000); 
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
                finally
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }                          
        };
        timer.start();   
    }                    
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound); 

    SharedPreferences getPrefs1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean music = getPrefs1.getBoolean("splash_music", true);
    if (music == true)      
    ourSong.start();

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000); 
                }
              catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
              finally{
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
            }
        };                                                                      
         timer.start();  
         }      
public void getPrefs() {  
    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager  
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());  

    boolean without_splash_screen = getPrefs.getBoolean("without_splash_screen", true);
    boolean splash = getPrefs.getBoolean("splash", false);       
    boolean music = getPrefs.getBoolean("splash_music", false);

    if (without_splash_screen == true){  
        splash = false; 
        music = false;                  
       }else if (splash == true){  
        music = false; 
        without_splash_screen = false;                       
       }else if (music == true){  
        without_splash_screen = false; 
        splash = false;  
    }
    }
   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPause();
ourSong.release();
finish();
  }
  }
```

**UPDATE:
i tried also another code but it doesn't change any thing , still all chechboxs can be checked :**

```
  public class Splash extends Activity{   
    MediaPlayer ourSong;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.splash);  

     SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());                 

     boolean without_splash_screen = getPrefs.getBoolean("without_splash_screen", true);
        if (without_splash_screen == true)
        {   
            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {       
            getPrefs.getBoolean("splash", false);       
            getPrefs.getBoolean("splash_music", false);
            }
boolean splash = getPrefs.getBoolean("splash", true);       
if(splash == true) {
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);  
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000); 
                }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            finally{
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                startActivity(intent);  
                }
            } 
        };                             
    timer.start();   
    }                
else
{
    getPrefs.getBoolean("without_splash_screen", false);       
    getPrefs.getBoolean("splash_music", false);
    }
ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound); 
boolean splash_music = getPrefs.getBoolean("splash_music", true);
if (splash_music == true)   {
    ourSong.start();
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);      
Thread timer = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(2000); 
            }
          catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
          finally{
              Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
              startActivity(intent); 
          }
      }                          
  };
  timer.start();   
  }                   
 else
  {
getPrefs.getBoolean("without_splash_screen", false);       
getPrefs.getBoolean("splash", false);
 }
   }
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPause();
  ourSong.release();
  finish();
      } 
   }
```

**Any advice , thanks.**

**UPDATE 3 (WHOLE PROJECT):**

**1- one checkbox checked achieved perfectly .**

**2- either using back button or exit button in MainActivity , doesn't respond to first click , i have to click twice or three times to exit the app.**

**Splash.java**

```
  public class Splash extends Activity{ 
MediaPlayer ourSong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle DrTsn) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(DrTsn);
         setContentView(R.layout.splash);  

         SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());                 

         boolean without_splash_screen = getPrefs.getBoolean("without_splash_screen", true);
            if (without_splash_screen == true)
            {                                              
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                  startActivity(intent);                        
            }

    boolean splash = getPrefs.getBoolean("splash", true);       
    if(splash == true) {
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);  
        Thread timer = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    sleep(2000); 
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
                finally
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                    startActivity(intent);  
                }
            }                          
        };
        timer.start();   
    }                    
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound); 

    SharedPreferences getPrefs1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean music = getPrefs1.getBoolean("splash_music", true);
    if (music == true)      
    ourSong.start();

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000); 
                }
              catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
              finally{
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                  startActivity(intent); 
                  }
            }
        };                                                                      
         timer.start();   
         }  
@Override
protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();
          } 
       }
```

**Prefs.java**

```
 public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {
  CheckBoxPreference splash;
  CheckBoxPreference splash_music;
  CheckBoxPreference no_splash_music;

 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

  splash = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("splash");
  splash_music = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("splash_music");
  no_splash_music = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("without_splash_screen");

  splash.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
            Object newValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        splash.setChecked(true);
        splash_music.setChecked(false);
        no_splash_music.setChecked(false);

        return true;
    }

});

splash_music
        .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                    Object newValue) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                splash.setChecked(false);
                splash_music.setChecked(true);
                no_splash_music.setChecked(false);

                return true;
            }

        });

no_splash_music
        .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                    Object newValue) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                splash.setChecked(false);
                splash_music.setChecked(false);
                no_splash_music.setChecked(true);

                return true;
            }
        });
  }
  }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {

MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);

getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {

if (name .equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
try {
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);

new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

((TextView) view).setTextSize(25);  
((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED); 
} 
}
);                                        
return view;
}
 catch (InflateException e) {        
 }
  catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {          
  }
}                                  
return null; 
}
}
);           
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);                                    
}   
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.aboutUs:
        Intent i = new Intent("com.example.checkbox.ABOUT");
        startActivity(i);
    break;
    case R.id.preferences:
        Intent p = new Intent("com.example.checkbox.PREFS");
        startActivity(p);
    break;
    case R.id.exit:
        finish();
    break;
}
return false;
   }
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
   }
```

**AboutUs.java**

```
     public class AboutUs extends Activity {
     @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
      setContentView(R.layout.about);  

      Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.about_button);           
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
              finish(); }
                      }
                  );}
                 }
```

Comment: Instead of check-box you can use radio-buttons with Radio-Group widget that will help you to select one option from three of them. If you want to make it look like checkBox create a drawable xml file for the checked and unchecked mode and apply it on button property of all the radio buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"FIRST only one checkbox should be checked ."

Not sure how to make this a short and easy answer, but hang with me, this works.

Create a preference activity that you call from your activity.

Use something like this in your onOptionSelected:

```
  case R.id.prefs:
        Intent p = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Prefs.class);
        startActivity(p);
        break;
```

This is the Prefs.class

```
public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {
CheckBoxPreference splash;
CheckBoxPreference splash_music;
CheckBoxPreference no_splash_music;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);



    splash = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("splash");
    splash_music = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("splash_music");
    no_splash_music = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("without_splash_screen");

    splash.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            splash.setChecked(true);
            splash_music.setChecked(false);
            no_splash_music.setChecked(false);

            return true;
        }

    });

    splash_music
            .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                        Object newValue) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    splash.setChecked(false);
                    splash_music.setChecked(true);
                    no_splash_music.setChecked(false);

                    return true;
                }

            });

    no_splash_music
            .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                        Object newValue) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    splash.setChecked(false);
                    splash_music.setChecked(false);
                    no_splash_music.setChecked(true);

                    return true;
                }

            });

   }

 }
```

And don't forget to add it to the Manifest:

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.lordmarty.testforlools.Prefs"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.lordmarty.testforlools.PREFS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The prefs.xml file is the same as the one you posted.

Let me know if you get any errors. I've tested it, and it works fine here.

"SECOND"

Not sure why you have to click twice. But it might be caused by the splash not finishing, just calling a new intent.
Try this where ever you start your mainclass from the splash:

```
  finally{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this,    MainActivity.class);                                     
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            }
```

Now, I've looked over your project and found out why it where so buggy.

Main reason:

```
     if (music == true)     
    ourSong.start();

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
```

Here you are missing a brackets for the if statement, causing the thread to run everytime. Therefore you have two MainActivities running at the same time.

Other notes: You use "if"'s for all the values. I suggest you use "else if".

And I did a small cleanup.

Here u go. Enjoy:

[Link to Splash.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tu14tptvd9kxtm8/Splash.java)

You can solve the last problem in many ways. One of them being this:

```
// add this below the other if else if statements in the splass.java
else if(without_splash_screen == false && splash == false && music == false){
//put whatever you want to happen if none of them are checked. This is just an example.
setContentView(R.layout.splash); 
        setContentView(R.layout.splash); 
        Thread timer = new Thread() { 
            public void run() { 
                try { 
                    sleep(2000); 
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } finally { 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, 
                            MainActivity.class); 
                    startActivity(intent); 
                    finish(); 


                } 
            } 
        }; 
        timer.start();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ,FIRST only one checkbox should be checked (work perfectly), but SECOND part of question still not achieved , also i used 
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
} it make nothing , any advice please.

Comment: I'm not able to help you with the second part because I don't have that problem on any of my devices. What device are you using?

Comment: and, do you have other classes in your app? hidden from us?
Like, when you press back once, does it look like it closes one activity but you still have one more to close?

Comment: just another 2 class Prefs Class writen as your answer and MainActivity which had option menu, i will upload it later

Comment: check UPDATE 3 (WHOLE PROJECT): also i will try now your updated answer regarding the intent , thanks

Comment: it doesnt solve it i install it its open mainactivity directly and music playing in back ground

Comment: i have strange behavior also , after install app and open pref then check splash without music and reopen app it open the splash with music  , then repeat the check another time the same , third time its behave as expected splash without music checkbox open app with splash without music

Comment: You should consider not having all of the preferences as default value "true". Might cause a fuzz. And do you really need to set the values in your splash.class when users now only can set one of the values?

Comment: And did you have to click the back button twice with the latest edit i posted? Even if the splash didn't show as planned. Just to see if the problem lies with the splash not finishing.

Comment: i will check now again also his link to download apk to check it if you want , this without finish after intent show press back many times to exit and show strange behavior of second checkbox(splash without music) . the link: http://www.mediafire.com/?164w5dv7vwvxrf2

Comment: i change it to be  android:defaultValue="true" only for first checkbox and the same, also i try now the intent with finsih also you have to press back button many times before exit , thanks really for your help

Comment: this is link to whole project for download , please check it , thanks :http://www.mediafire.com/?iv9cab5b420b5a9

Comment: @ LordMarty that whole project link with finish after intent you can check it then remove finish and check it , it will be cleared like this , thanks

Comment: ok i test it its work but one more thing , if you unchecked all ( the 3 check boxs) , then reopen app its open on splash screen without music an stack on it , so it must be always one checkbox checked and we cant unchecked all , do you get me , thanks

Comment: Check the updated answer, and it's time to accept the answer :)

Comment: all perfect now , just explanation please to understand only , i put your last code for all uncheckboxs , it gave me yellow line error under(timer) in ( Thread timer = new Thread() { ) , why and to correct it eclipse remove that line and lead to stack on splash without music again .(by the way i need it to start without splash in case of all unchecked and i do it correctly ), i ask you just to know please

Comment: for all your help and support my dear sir , +1 upvote , accept and bounty , thanks indeed.

Comment: Think it's because I forgot the " timer.start();". Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to change it to

```
    boolean without_splash_screen = getPrefs.getBoolean("without_splash_screen", true);
    boolean splash = getPrefs.getBoolean("splash", true);
    boolean splash_music = getPrefs.getBoolean("splash_music", true);

    if (without_splash_screen)
    {   
        ...
    }
    else if (splash)
    {
         ...
    }
    else if (splash_music)
    {
        ....
    }
```

Comment: i run the app it start with splash screen without music but stack on splash and not go to next activity

Comment: If you want them to be able to check only one then why not use a `RadioGroup` instead of `CheckBox`es?

Comment: i know that but id like to do it by using checkbox

Comment: That's great that its what you want but you need to do what makes sense to the users. To the users, if you have `CheckBoxes` then they think they should be able to check multiple items. You should use `RadioButton`s or `ToggleButton`s. But what is the real problem you are having?

Comment: my above code add 3 checkedbox with different functions but still i need to check one only and can not check the others , i try your code , it doesn't achieve that , any advice my friend , thanks

Comment: You can do it as you are...just replace the `CheckBoxes` with `RadioButtons` and wrap them in a `RadioGroup`. This will ensure that only one may be checked at a time. Your users will thank you for it

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Radio buttons inside preference activity that looks like check boxes as follows..

[image]

Only one can be selected at a time.
I done this using 2 more xml files

[image]

One inside drawable(check_dyn.xml) and another inside layout(radiochecks.xml) .

**check_dyn.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background" />
</selector>
```

**radiochecks.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/check_dyn"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="RadioButton1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/check_dyn"
            android:text="RadioButton2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/check_dyn"
            android:text="RadioButton3" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, inside the preference,(here prefs.xml), add a preference and set its layout property. ie,

```
<Preference android:layout="@layout/radiochecks"
    />
```

Note: I don't prefer a practice like this, since it is hard to get the individual values.

I prefer ->

[image: From settings]
[image]

Comment: ((it is hard to get the individual values.)) , this is the point im new to android and i know your solution before i try it but i cant get the values as to perform its action