# PreferenceActivity Screen

Tags: android

I'm working on my settings as you can see from my xml and class. my onPreferenceChange is not setting the 2nd and 3rd toggle buttons to false when the first 1st toggle button is set to false.

Logcat

```
07-23 16:10:42.879: I/PROJECTCARUSO(11579): preference: Cervical Mucus Are you observing MucusnewValue: true
07-23 16:10:42.879: I/PROJECTCARUSO(11579): True
07-23 16:10:44.601: I/PROJECTCARUSO(11579): preference: Cervical Mucus Are you observing MucusnewValue: false
07-23 16:10:44.611: I/PROJECTCARUSO(11579): True
```

Class:

```
public class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceChangeListener{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /**
     * Populate the activity with the top-level headers.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","onBuildHeaders");
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);

    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows the preferences for the first header.
     */
    public static class Prefs1Fragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.notification_settings);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows the preferences for the second header.
     */
    public static class Prefs2Fragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.charting_settings);

            findPreference("cervical_mucus").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
                    new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                           @Override
                           public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                               Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","preference: "+ preference + "newValue: " + newValue);
                               SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

                               // string test w/o "==" usage.
                               if ("false".equals(newValue)) {
                                   prefs.edit().putBoolean("mucus_stamps", false).commit();
                                   prefs.edit().putBoolean("fertile_infertil", false).commit();
                               } else {
                                   prefs.edit().putBoolean("mucus_stamps", true).commit();
                                   prefs.edit().putBoolean("fertile_infertil", true).commit();
                               }

                               // remove all and reload
                               getPreferenceScreen().removeAll();

                               //NAMEOFXML is the same you have in your fragement's oncreate
                               addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers);

                               // true instead of false so the new value gets kept
                               return true;
                           };
                    });
        }
    }

    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }


}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory 
         android:title="@string/pref_chart_profile" 
         android:textSize="20px">

        <SwitchPreference  
                android:title="@+string/pref_symptothermal"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_symptothermal_summary"
                android:key="symptothermal"
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:layout="@layout/pref_layout"/>

        <SwitchPreference 
                android:id="@+id/cervical_mucus"
                android:title="@+string/pref_cervical_mucus"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_cervical_mucus_summary"
                android:key="cervical_mucus"
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:layout="@layout/pref_layout" />    

        <SwitchPreference 
                android:id="@+id/mucus_stamps"
                android:title="@+string/pref_mucus_stamps"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_mucus_stamps_summary"
                android:key="mucus_stamps"
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:layout="@layout/pref_layout" />

        <SwitchPreference 
                android:id="@+id/fertile_infertil"
                android:title="@+string/pref_fertile_infertile"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_fertile_infertile_summary"
                android:key="fertile_infertil" 
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:layout="@layout/pref_layout" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.

Define the SwitchPreferences right below your class like this:

```
  SwitchPreference mucus_stamps;
  SwitchPreference cervical_mucus;
```

Then give the switch a view:
      cervical_mucus = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("cervical_mucus");
      mucus_stamps = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("mucus_stamps");

Now set the onchange listener:

```
mucus_stamps.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mucus_stamps.setChecked(true);
            cervical_mucus.setChecked(false);
                            //here you set the others to false.


            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: frequency is not even defined

Comment: The values are getting set just fine. Its that the view isn't refreshing to show the new values.

Comment: Well, if you do it like I mention, the view will be updated.
[More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625830/only-select-one-checkbox-of-splash-preference-checkedboxs/17800690#17800690)

Comment: setValue does not seem to be valid for SwitchPreference.

Comment: Sorry. Was answering from my phone, wasn't sure if it was value or what it was. Edited and working now. Even tested. Gl hf :)

Comment: And note, when editing in a PreferenceActivity, you don't need to commit and such.

Comment: PERFECT! Works like a charm

Comment: Now quick question how can i disable those two also?

Comment: you need to find their views by calling the same findPreference. Then just set them the same way.  someotherpref.setchecked(false)

Answer (score 1):

```
        findPreference("cervical_mucus").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
             new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                        Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","preference: "+ preference + "newValue: " + newValue);
                        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

                        // string test w/o "==" usage.
                        if ("false".equals(newValue)) {
                            prefs.edit().putBoolean("mucus_stamps", false).commit();
                            prefs.edit().putBoolean("fertile_infertil", false).commit();
                        } else {
                            prefs.edit().putBoolean("mucus_stamps", true).commit();
                            prefs.edit().putBoolean("fertile_infertil", true).commit();
                        }

                        // remove all and reload
                        getPreferenceScreen().removeAll();
                        //NAMEOFXML is the same you have in your fragement's oncreate
                        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.NAMEOFXML);

                        // true instead of false so the new value gets kept
                        return true;
                    };
             });
```

Comment: answer wasn't exactly this but close see my edit. However its not setting those two toggles to false.

Comment: It seems that it is not refreshing the view.